# Getting Scala type bound error: not found: type <%<

Tags: scala, type-bounds

So I've been trying to learn Scala through the [twitter Scala school](http://twitter.github.com/scala_school). But I'm currently stuck at one of their [type bound examples](http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/advanced-types.html#otherbounds).

In particular, it's the one where the type is bound to be viewable as a certain type, using the `<%<` type-relation operator.

When I execute the following code in my Scala console:

```
scala> class Container[A](value: A) { def addIt(implicit evidence: A <%< Int) = 123 + value }
```

... I get the following errors:

```
<console>:7: error: not found: type <%<
       class Container[A](value: A) { def addIt(implicit evidence: A <%< Int) = 123 + value }
                                                                     ^
<console>:7: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int <and>
  (x: String)String
 cannot be applied to (A)
       class Container[A](value: A) { def addIt(implicit evidence: A <%< Int) = 123 + value }
```

My question is, why is the Scala interpreter complaining?

I've been trying to look through the Scala documentation but I haven't been able to find information that operator anywhere. I can see that the Scala school was created on the basis of Scala 2.8.0, and I'm running Scala 2.10.0 - so maybe this have been removed? If this is the case, why is this as it seems like a useful operator?

Comment: Looks like this isn't there in Scala 2.10, though I'm not sure exactly why - https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L1

Comment: Was deprecated in https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/e1780e9686914d835b295e125511368eeb1d0733#L0L350

Comment: Well found! Looks like precisely the reason I guessed at below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constraint `A <%< B` in Scala 2.8 is defined as

```
  sealed abstract class <%<[-From, +To] extends (From => To)
  object <%< {
    implicit def conformsOrViewsAs[A <% B, B]: A <%< B = new (A <%< B) {def apply(x: A) = x}
  }
```

So you can always bring it back that way. However, I'm guessing that the reason it's deprecated is that a view bound is just asking for an implicit function from `A` to `B`, and there's a perfectly good way to express that particular constraint in a generalised way already:

```
class Container[A](value: A) { def addIt(implicit evidence: A => Int) = 123 + value }
```

As an aside, it's worth noting that is isn't an operator, but a class in infix position as you can see from the definition. The same is true for `=>`, which is just another way of referencing the `Function1` type constructor.

Comment: I've been searching a bit for an official reasoning behind the removal of the class, but without any luck. Your guess is as good as anyone's and enough to satisfy my curiosity, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

On [this site](http://scalabound.org/?page_id=201#G), it says that `A <%< B` got deprecated in Scala 2.9. I don't know why, and I agree it seems a bit odd as it to me also looks like a pretty useful operator.

Comment: As described on the GitHub change at https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/e1780e9686914d835b295e125511368eeb1d0733#L0L350, `A => B` is to be used in place of  `A <%< B` since they have the same semantics.

Answer (score -1):

The correct usage seems to be

```
class Container[A](value: A) { def addIt[A <% Int] = 123 + value }
```

As for the overloaded values, `scala` is choosing not to resolve the ambiguity; in which case, you have to decide.

- you can try debugging with: `-Xprint:typer`
- or you can decide that `A` is indeed `Int` by either using `class Container[A](value: A) { def addIt = 123 + value.asInstanceOf[Int] }` or the already suggested `class Container[A](value: A) { def addIt(implicit evidence: A => Int) = 123 + value }`. They are equivalent. But  here you are saying that `A` is a type of `Int`; as opposed to `A` can be viewed as `Int` which is what `<%` does.

That second option is not trivial. Consider the following

```
scala> class Container[A](value: A) { def printIt[A <% Int] = println( 123+" could be " + value) }
defined class Container

scala> val x = new Container("Love")
x: Container[String] = Container@21ebfd82

scala> x.printIt
123 could be Love
```

Clearly `"love"` is not a type of `Int` because it is `String`, yet it's perfectly fine in this context: which is why you should be careful about using `A => Int`.

Comment: The snippet at the top is most definitely not the correct usage! The type parameter `A` on the 'addIt' method is shadowing the parameter `A` on the class, so adds nothing to this situation.

Comment: Your second example works only because of a global implicit `any2stringAdd` which lets any type be converted to a string for the purposes of concatenating it - which is entirely co-incidental to this question. Also, it's not true to say that `{ def addIt = 123 + value.asInstanceOf[Int] }` and `{ def addIt(implicit evidence: A => Int) = 123 + value }` are equivalent. One is an unsafe cast which will blow up at compile time for anything not a subtype of Int. The other is type-safe, relying on an implicit conversion being in scope.

Comment: Sorry, blow up at run time, not compile time.